# Convert stored procedure output from dapper.net into List

Tags: c#, dapper

I am new to Dapper.net, I am trying to execute a stored procedure using Dapper.Net.

I have a model class `StoredProcedureResult`, related the stored procedure's output.

```
public StoredProcedureResult
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

conn.Query(SP_name, Param(s), Type).
```

The output of the model is retrieved dynamic.

After executing I get the following

```
{{Dapper,Name='Pradeep',Address='UK',PhoneNumber='+4478923984'}}
{{Dapper,Name='Jack',Address='USA',PhoneNumber='+447242344234}}
{{Dapper,Name='Ram',Address='UK',PhoneNumber='+447892423484'}}
```

I require to convert the dynamic output in `List<StoredProcedureResult>` structure.

After few search I found this code

```
conn.Query<*Model_name*>(SP_name, Param(s), Type).
```

Unfortunately this return the right number of rows but the rows are empty. How can I convert the output into a `List<StoredProcedureResult>`.

Thanks

Comment: This is a question about dapper. removed the irrelevant tags Sql-server and stored-procedure.

Comment: Do you get any output in your procedure call ? Feels like the problem is you do not get any rows returned, otherwise creating a list with the ouput should not be an issue.

Comment: I executed the SP from SSMS, I got the result from it. When I execute the same SP from Dapper I get the above mentioned output ({{Dapperrow... in above). However when I try to add a model instead of dynamic I am not able to capture and value in the rows. I am trying to convert SP output into List<StoredProcedureResult> or something similar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify the return type of the data when you call the Query.

- Where you have <*Model Name*> is where you'd put the expected return type - .
- In your example you're getting data back in dapper's internal dynamic dapperrow type

```cs
// Gets results in dapper's DapperRow type. 
// This is what you're getting now. 
var results = _connection.Query("SP_name", 
                      commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

The example below shows returning the results in your named type which is what you actually want.

```cs
// Gets results in your type. Note we tell dapper 
// we want it turned into StoredProcedureResults.
List<StoredProcedureResult> castResults;
castResults = _connection.Query<StoredProcedureResult>(
                   "SP_name", 
                   commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
```

Comment: Thansk G Davison. It worked and I am able to get the Model output defined my me.